# how can i turn off my read receipts?

Tags: iphone, messages

So my friend can see when i read her messages but i’m confused i have my read receipts off? like i’ve tried youtube videos to see if there’s other ways to turn it off but there’s only 2, the settings and on the message thing (send receipts) and they are both off, I’m confused on how she seeing them?

Comment: Is it only that particular friend or someone else can also see your read receipts even if your settings are both off (globally at iMessage settings and individually at message receiver settings)? If you just made the change, it may take a while to apply. Maybe a restart or a waiting time is required.

Comment: @elegantcomplexity she’s the only one for some reason. i asked others if they can see and they said no :/